# Mobile detection for specific parts of websites

Tags: html, mobile, video, detection

I am beginner in web development and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this problem.

I have taken a video and encoded it into an mp4 file and an ism file. I have two different video tags- one that will play each file. For the website I'm working on I would like it to use one of the video tags if the website is being viewed on a mobile device, and the other if it is not. Right now the website is in HTML5. Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

you could either use UserAgent based detection to decide what to show (not recommended as you have to maintain it) or `canPlayType()` with the codec you are using to see if the browser supports it (better option)

Answer (score 0):

The video tag already supports alternate sources.  The article [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) describes how to include multiple sources for a video (because some browsers don't work with certain codecs).  Like so:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For mobile checks you can use JavaScript CSS media queries:

```
function isMobile() {
    return window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 320px)" );
}
```

See [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/)