# overall html5 video failure: image/ogg error?

Tags: html, video, ogg

Every browser, with exception of Chrome will not properly display my HTML5 video.
http://cordeck.ba.lightburncloud.com/test-video

Here is my markup:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="" autoplay="" preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
    <source type="video/ogg" src="/files/videos/sample.ogg">
</video>
```

Firefox, for instance, displays the following message within my video box:

```
No video with supported format and MIME type found
```

In the error console, I get the following message:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "image/ogg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://http://cordeck.ba.lightburncloud.com//files/videos/sample.ogg failed.
```

To my knowledge, image/ogg type does not exist, nor do I use it in my site. What gives?

Comment: What `Content-Type` header is your webserver sending? Make sure it is `video/ogg`.

Comment: It is sending video/ogg

Comment: Have you read: http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html?

Comment: "Every browser, with exception of Chrome"...this is too common a problem. Chrome is just too good ;D

Comment: I'd try the canPlayType test to see if the browser thinks it can play - not perfect, but might help narrow down what will work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097554/mobile-detection-for-specific-parts-of-websites/15123708#15123708

Comment: I advise also making MP4 and WebM versions of the video and a Youtube/flash fallback (putting the MP4 source first), for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved. Apparently the CMS serving up the image was attaching its own MIME types and storing them alongside the file in the database.

The web server was sending the correct type, but getting overridden by a third party app.