# Firefox video support

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, codec

I want to play html5 videos in my page but there are certain videos that cannot be played in firefox or edge, but can be played in chrome. Firefox says "Video can't be played because the file is corrupt." and edge just doesn't play it, no error or anything.

This is the codec for the video that all three browsers can play:
[image: Codec 1]

This is the codec for the video only the chrome can play:
[image: Codec 2]

I tried playing the video from a direct url, without an html5 video tag, but still the same things are happening. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Update: I know that not every browser supports all the codecs but I am asking what is the exact codec problem here, because I could not find out which codec setting is causing the problem. I am using H264 MPEG-4 AVC codec for both of the videos.

Comment: Duplicate of [Videos not playing in browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450965/videos-not-playing-in-browsers)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I already checked that, but the problem is that I can play another H264 MPEG-4 video in firefox and edge

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Its is not searchable, and the font and size can not be changed which means some people cant read it. And it not searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Decoded format: Planar 4:4:4 YUV`

This sampling is not supported by the majority of decoders. You must reencode the file to 4:2:0